# Python library osmnx not working with Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, osmnx

I am using Mac and from the terminal, I could access the osmnx; however, osmnx features do not run from spyder. I am trying to use osmnx in a script to automate the process.
When I try running a simple script such as:

```
import osmnx as ox
graph = ox.load_graphml('NL_motorway.graphml')
```

I get the following errors:

```
File "", line 1, in 
runfile('/Users/salilsharma/surfdrive/My Documents/python/Ksp/osmnx.py', wdir='/Users/salilsharma/surfdrive/My Documents/python/Ksp')

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/Users/salilsharma/surfdrive/My Documents/python/Ksp/osmnx.py", line 9, in 
import osmnx as ox

File "/Users/salilsharma/surfdrive/My Documents/python/Ksp/osmnx.py", line 11, in 
graph = ox.load_graphml('NL_motorway.graphml')
AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute 'load_graphml'
```

I am using the following software. 
OS: MacOS Mojave 10.14.1, python 3.6.5, OSMNX version 0.8.2.

Comment: I think this happens because you're running a file (`My Documents/python/Ksp/osmnx.py`) which has the same name as the module itself, and that's confusing Python. So you just need to rename that file and you'll avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks. The error disappeared but it presented me with another error. 
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/NL_motorway.graphml'` The file is present in the same directory though.

Comment: If it's in the same directory, then you don't need the `data/` part.